# localhost cannot be reached with Airflow running

Tags: ubuntu, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have cloned puckel's airflow container project and loaded the container in Ubuntu. It seems like airflow container is running fine after the initial load(see log below), but I can't connect to localhost port 8080 which is the port exposed for looking at the airflow UI

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nWn1.png
airflow Dockerfile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OR1k.png

I feel it's something trivial that I have overlooked, but I spent hours troubleshooting it and it's driving me crazy. Anyone has any suggestions?

Things tried: -user privilege (sudo, root) -restarting VM -restarting computer

```
root@VirtualBox:~/GIT/docker-airflow# docker run 9201870f6b60
[2019-06-04 21:50:23,076] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
DB: sqlite:////usr/local/airflow/airflow/airflow.db
[2019-06-04 21:50:24,200] {{db.py:338}} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> e3a246e0dc1, current schema
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade e3a246e0dc1 -> 1507a7289a2f, create is_encrypted
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/messaging.py:69: UserWarning: Skipping unsupported ALTER for creation of implicit constraint
  warnings.warn(msg)
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1507a7289a2f -> 13eb55f81627, maintain history for compatibility with earlier migrations
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 13eb55f81627 -> 338e90f54d61, More logging into task_instance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 338e90f54d61 -> 52d714495f0, job_id indices
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 52d714495f0 -> 502898887f84, Adding extra to Log
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 502898887f84 -> 1b38cef5b76e, add dagrun
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1b38cef5b76e -> 2e541a1dcfed, task_duration
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2e541a1dcfed -> 40e67319e3a9, dagrun_config
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 40e67319e3a9 -> 561833c1c74b, add password column to user
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 561833c1c74b -> 4446e08588, dagrun start end
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 4446e08588 -> bbc73705a13e, Add notification_sent column to sla_miss
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade bbc73705a13e -> bba5a7cfc896, Add a column to track the encryption state of the 'Extra' field in connection
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade bba5a7cfc896 -> 1968acfc09e3, add is_encrypted column to variable table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1968acfc09e3 -> 2e82aab8ef20, rename user table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2e82aab8ef20 -> 211e584da130, add TI state index
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 211e584da130 -> 64de9cddf6c9, add task fails journal table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 64de9cddf6c9 -> f2ca10b85618, add dag_stats table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade f2ca10b85618 -> 4addfa1236f1, Add fractional seconds to mysql tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 4addfa1236f1 -> 8504051e801b, xcom dag task indices
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 8504051e801b -> 5e7d17757c7a, add pid field to TaskInstance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 5e7d17757c7a -> 127d2bf2dfa7, Add dag_id/state index on dag_run table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 127d2bf2dfa7 -> cc1e65623dc7, add max tries column to task instance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade cc1e65623dc7 -> bdaa763e6c56, Make xcom value column a large binary
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade bdaa763e6c56 -> 947454bf1dff, add ti job_id index
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 947454bf1dff -> d2ae31099d61, Increase text size for MySQL (not relevant for other DBs' text types)
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade d2ae31099d61 -> 0e2a74e0fc9f, Add time zone awareness
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade d2ae31099d61 -> 33ae817a1ff4, kubernetes_resource_checkpointing
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 33ae817a1ff4 -> 27c6a30d7c24, kubernetes_resource_checkpointing
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 27c6a30d7c24 -> 86770d1215c0, add kubernetes scheduler uniqueness
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 86770d1215c0, 0e2a74e0fc9f -> 05f30312d566, merge heads
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 05f30312d566 -> f23433877c24, fix mysql not null constraint
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade f23433877c24 -> 856955da8476, fix sqlite foreign key
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 856955da8476 -> 9635ae0956e7, index-faskfail
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 9635ae0956e7 -> dd25f486b8ea
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade dd25f486b8ea -> bf00311e1990, add index to taskinstance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 9635ae0956e7 -> 0a2a5b66e19d, add task_reschedule table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 0a2a5b66e19d, bf00311e1990 -> 03bc53e68815, merge_heads_2
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 03bc53e68815 -> 41f5f12752f8, add superuser field
Done.
[2019-06-04 21:50:27,875] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/

[2019-06-04 21:50:28,738] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:50:30 +0000] [18] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-06-04 21:50:30 +0000] [18] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (18)
[2019-06-04 21:50:30 +0000] [18] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-06-04 21:50:30 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
[2019-06-04 21:50:30 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
[2019-06-04 21:50:30 +0000] [25] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25
[2019-06-04 21:50:30 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
[2019-06-04 21:50:31,002] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================            
[2019-06-04 21:50:31,224] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:50:31,316] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:50:31,335] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:50:32,196] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:50:32,335] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:50:32,410] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:50:32,416] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:51:03 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:51:03 +0000] [39] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 39
[2019-06-04 21:51:03,250] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:51:03,872] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:51:04 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:51:04 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
[2019-06-04 21:51:34 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:51:34 +0000] [43] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 43
[2019-06-04 21:51:34,636] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:51:35,204] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:51:35 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:51:35 +0000] [24] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24)
[2019-06-04 21:52:05 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:52:05 +0000] [47] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47
[2019-06-04 21:52:05,935] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:52:06,508] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:52:06 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:52:06 +0000] [25] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25)
[2019-06-04 21:52:37 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:52:37 +0000] [51] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 51
[2019-06-04 21:52:37,311] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:52:37,894] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:52:38 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:52:38 +0000] [26] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 26)
[2019-06-04 21:53:08 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:53:08 +0000] [55] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55
[2019-06-04 21:53:08,815] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:53:09,385] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:53:09 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:53:09 +0000] [39] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 39)
[2019-06-04 21:53:40 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:53:40 +0000] [59] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 59
[2019-06-04 21:53:40,171] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:53:40,737] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:53:41 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:53:41 +0000] [43] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 43)
[2019-06-04 21:54:11 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:54:11 +0000] [63] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63
[2019-06-04 21:54:11,525] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:54:12,107] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:54:12 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:54:12 +0000] [47] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 47)
[2019-06-04 21:54:42 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:54:42 +0000] [67] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 67
[2019-06-04 21:54:42,871] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:54:43,440] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:54:43 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:54:43 +0000] [51] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 51)
[2019-06-04 21:55:14 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-06-04 21:55:14 +0000] [71] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 71
[2019-06-04 21:55:14,318] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-06-04 21:55:14,896] {{models.py:273}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-06-04 21:55:15 +0000] [18] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-06-04 21:55:15 +0000] [55] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 55)
```

Comment: Did you actually map the port when you started your container? Have you nmap'd localhost?

Comment: @HSchmale ahhh, that's it. I was thinking of launching airflow webserver, didn't specify port mapping. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @HSchmale pointed, forgot to map port. docker run -p 8080:8080  fixed the issue